# How can I save an XmlDocument without the XML Prolog?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, csproj

While working on csproj files as xml files (`xmlDocument`) somehow after saving, encoding changes from UTF-8 to ASCII. The only solution I figured out is to use `StreamWriter` with declared encoding. But this adds a header to file. 
Questions:
1. Do you know any other solution to this problem?
2. Can I leave changed csproj?

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(projectFilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
XmlDocument xmlCsproj = new XmlDocument();
xmlCsproj.Load(sr);
sr.Close();

// Working on XML nodes (replace references paths)

StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter(projectFilePath, false, Encoding.UTF8);
xmlCsproj.Save(sw);
sw.Close();
```

Comment: What header are you referring to?  If it is the ident line why do you want it removed?   Try deleting the file and run program again.

Comment: The encoding would only change if your code changes it. StreamWriter doesn't even know about XM, it just writes strings to a file. Post your code.

Comment: because it shows changes in the revision control system and not always something changes there despite header.

Comment: @AdG post your code. StreamWriter knows nothing about headers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Done

Comment: When you said header, did you mean BOM? Byte Order Masks? Like the first 3 bytes?

Comment: BTW if it is BOM, to get rid of it, use `new UTF8Encoding(false)`.

Comment: @weichch a mean this : "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"

Comment: @AdG this code doesn't add any headers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but some way new line appears ;)

Comment: @AdG `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is the standard XML prolog, not a header. It's optional but all *XML* serializers emit it. It's created by `XmlDocument.Save`, not StreamWriter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so are there any properties to set to not insert this prolog?

Comment: Interestingly, it's only when save to a text writer with encoding, the declaration is added. i.e. saving to *file path* does not seem to have that added.

Comment: Wait what does `encoding changes from UTF-8 to ASCII` mean? A csproj file typically contains English text only, and UTF8 is *identical* to 7-bit US-ASCII for characters in the range 0-127. Did you store non-english file names perhaps?

Comment: Your editor may report the encoding to be ASCII if there's no characters outside the ascii range, even when it's saved as utf-8!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work?

```
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(projectFilePath, Encoding.UTF8)
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
xmlCsproj.WriteContentTo(writer);
writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, UTF8 character values are identical to US-ASCII values in the range 0-127. There's no way to say if a csproj file was saved as US-ASCII or UTF8 unless the file contained non-English text, like non-English file paths. Is that what happened here? Even so, `XmlDocument.Save` should have used UTF8 by default.

You can control how an XmlDocument is written to a stream or file using an XmlWriter and XmlWriterSettings. In this case, you need to set the [OmitXmlDeclaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration?view=netframework-4.8) :

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

var writer = XmlWriter.Create(projectFilePath, settings);
xmlCsproj.Save(sw);
sw.Close();
```

The default encoding is UTF8. To change it, you can set the [XmlWriterSettings.Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding?view=netframework-4.8) to a different value